# Best areas to farm skill points in Resident Evil 6

Tags: resident-evil-6

I want upgrades, and clearing every area for 100 point increments sees pointless.

What are the most time-efficient areas for making bank? What chapters with what perks activated? How does difficulty affect drops? Is Mercenaries more effective than Campaign?

Answer (score 3):

Chris - Chapter 5 - reloading/repeating checkpoint 1 - Averages 100-120k p/hour

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is way better in Mercenaries because:

1. You aren't progressing in the campaign
2. If you are a decent shooter playing you will rack up skill points.

Answer (score 0):

Chapter no 2 of Leon, get the 5000 icon from the graveyard and then kill the 4 screamers at the cemetery after Leon falls and then kill all the enemies outside the cathedral, once you have done that, get into the cathedral, quit after the saving point and you will end up with 12 to 15 skill points, it takes around 8 minutes but is worthwhile.